# Python Threading Module and scp

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-3.x, scp

Не могу никак побороть проблему с копированием файлов в несколько потоков.
Задача:
есть директории `dir1 = /home/my_dir1` и `dir2 = /home/my_dir2`. Как, используя модуль многопоточности, одновременно скопировать несколько файлов из `dir1` в `dir2`.
При этом есть `list` co всеми директориями внутри `dir1`.

```
remote_dir1 = '/home/my_dir1/'
def listdir_fullpath(d):
    return [os.path.join(d, f) for f in os.listdir(d)]

listdirs = sorted(listdir_fullpath(remote_dir1))
```

Comment: Пул потоков—это простой способ скопировать список файлов, заданное число параллельно: [How to download a few files simultaneusly from ftp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16501351/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за верное направление lebedev-ilya!
Решение задачи:

```
from threading import Thread
import os
from queue import Queue

q = Queue(maxsize=0)
q.put('/dir1/one')
q.put('/dir1/two')
q.put('/dir1/three')

tread = 3

def scp(q):
    while True:
        os.system('scp ' +  q.get() + ' ' + '/dir2/')
        q.task_done()

for i in range(tread):
    worker = Thread(target=scp, args=(q,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

q.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Пройтись по всем файлам в директории и положить полные пути к каждому из файлов в [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).
2. Создать n потоков ([threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)), каждый из которых берёт файл из Queue и копирует его в новое место до тех пор, пока очередь не опустеет.

По ссылкам есть примеры, с кодом, который демонстрирует этот подход. Это – один из стандартных способ независимой многопоточной обработки элементов сиска.